# R or Python geometry checker that outputs results as table

Tags: python, r, geometry, topology

Is there a R or Python solution that 1) checks the geometry validity of vectors and 2) outputs the results in form of a table (see table below). QGIS for example has a nice [plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html) that carries out several geometry checks. But how can I carry out these checks within a R or Python script?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `R` there is package [`cleangeo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cleangeo/cleangeo.pdf) for geometry checking and celaning. You can use for example:

```
library(cleangeo)
report <- clgeo_CollectionReport(spatial_object)
report

#returns a table:

            type valid    issue_type
1           <NA>  TRUE          <NA>
2 rgeos_validity FALSE GEOM_VALIDITY
3    rgeos_error FALSE ORPHANED_HOLE
                                                                                   error_msg
1                                                                                       <NA>
2                                                                                       <NA>
3 rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 7
                                                               warning_msg
1                                                                     <NA>
2 Ring Self-intersection at or near point -120.78997488 38.344996299999998
3     

                                                            <NA>
```

for summary you can do something like this:

```
summary(report[3])
#returns:
        issue_type
GEOM_VALIDITY:1   
ORPHANED_HOLE:1   
NA's         :1
```

Comment: I came along this package during my search but found it a bit limiting in comparison to the qgis plugin mentioned above. I feel that the qgis plugin allows me to check my geometries more thoroughly. Especially as I cannot seem to find duplicates, overlaps, minimum area polygons etc. What is your experience?

Comment: You could use [RQGIS](https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS) to call the QGIS plugin directly maybe?